# Snap with padding?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, snapping

In the API documentation I see Snap, SnapMode and SnapTolerance; none of which seem to do what I want.  I have multiple draggable divs in my UI that snap together, which is great, but I have added a dropshadow so I would really like them to snap but stay 5 or 10 pixels apart from eachother.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did end up creating an invisible outer container with 10 pixel padding, but this is pretty much an exact duplicate of the question I referenced in the close request.